# Reactjs Connect Select tags to ToggleButton

Tags: reactjs

Reactjs!
Hello,I am new to reactjs. I am trying to connect select tag with classname (dropdownbutton1 & dropdownbutton2) to togglebutton so that when ToggleButton is turned on, the Select tag dropdown button's border highlights and is set to be required.Here I am attaching my .jsx and .css files.Please Help.

```
<div className='ToggleButton'>
  <ToggleButton onClick={this.togglebutton} 
                checked={this.state.active}/>
</div>

<div className='dropdownbutton1'>
  <label>First</label>
  <br/>
  <select defaultValue={-1}>
    <option disabled value={-1}> </option>
    <option value='yes'>yes</option>
    <option value='no'>no</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div className='dropdownbutton2' >
  <label>Second</label>
  <br/>
  <select defaultValue={-1}>
   <option disabled value={-1}> </option>
   <option value='One'>One</option>
   <option value='Two'>Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

.css file

```
.ToggleButton {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1/2;
 }
. dropdownbutton1 {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 2/3;

}
. dropdownbutton2 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

Comment: are u looking to change the option value or the just highlighting the select menu

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/13nxlprnwq

Comment: I am looking to just higlight the dropdown button when toggle button turns on.so it looks like it is required to complete the step.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ypn0y11789

Comment: @SanjayA  it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSX:

```
    import React from "react";
    import ToggleButton from "react-toggle-button";
    import "./demo.css";

    class Demo extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          active: false
        };
      }

      togglebutton = () => {
        this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
      };
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="ToggleButton">
              <ToggleButton onClick={this.togglebutton} value={this.state.active} />
            </div>

            <div className="dropdownbutton1">
              <label>First</label>
              <br />
              <select className={this.state.active ? "dropdownActive" : null}>
                <option disabled value={1} />
                <option value="yes">yes</option>
                <option value="no">no</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div className="dropdownbutton2">
              <label>Second</label>
              <br />
              <select className={this.state.active ? "dropdownActive" : null}>
                <option disabled value={1} />
                <option value="One">One</option>
                <option value="Two">Two</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Demo;
```

CSS:

```
     .ToggleButton {
      grid-column: 4;
      grid-row: 1/2;
    }
    .dropdownbutton1 {
      grid-column: 4;
      grid-row: 2/3;
    }
    .dropdownbutton2 select {
      grid-column: 3;
      grid-row: 2/3;
    }
    .dropdownbutton1 select {
      grid-column: 4;
      grid-row: 2/3;
    }


    .dropdownActive  {
      color: red;
    }
```

Heres active codesandbox link [https://codesandbox.io/s/x36ox4yomp]